# TransactionManagementError and IntegrityError in Django tests even if atomic context is used

Tags: django

I'm trying to handle an Integrity Error in the Django tests (using `TestCase`), and while it seems to work for almost all tests I have, only one fails.

I overrode the save method on my model:

```
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.clean()
        try:
            return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        except IntegrityError as e:
            if len(e.args) >= 1:
                if "constraint_name_1" in str(e):
                    raise ValidationError(_('Error message 1'))
                elif "constraint_name_2" in str(e):
                    raise ValidationError(_('Error message 2'))
            raise e
```

and I wrap the test with `transaction.atomic` context to handle the error but it still fails.